# Asynchronously update state hook in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set a state generated by `useState` in an async function, but I found if I do like this, react would render my component infinitely.

This is a demo I made

```js
export const App = () => {
    const [nodes, setNodes] = useState([])

    // some async refresh code, like http request, like axios.get("/list-nodes").then ...
    const refresh = async () => {
        let arr = []
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            arr.push(Math.random())
        }
        setNodes(arr)
    }

    refresh();


    return (
        <div>
            {
                nodes.map(v =>
                    <div>
                        value: {v}
                    </div>)
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

In the code, the rendering is continuously happening and the numbers are keeping changing.

May I ask how I am able to set a state in an async function correctly?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async`.  It's rendering indefinitely because on each render you update state, and updating state triggers a re-render.  What's the goal here?  Why do you think you want to update state on every render?

Comment: I want to have a list of items show in screen, but the list can be updated by the http request. So each time I need to update the list I call the `refresh`. So at the beginning I `refresh` once, and after that, when something is updated I again call `refresh` to refresh the list shown on screen

Comment: *"each time I need to update the list I call the refresh"* - Not in the code shown you don't.  In the code shown you call `refresh()` **on every render**.  What is this HTTP request you refer to?  What **should** trigger the state to be updated?  It sounds like the example provided isn't demonstrating the scope of the problem.

Comment: I want to refresh the list at beginning (like I can fetch the list by doing stuff such as `axios.get("/list").then(resp => setNodes(resp.data))`, and then refresh the list from user's behaviours like adding/deleting

Comment: *"then refresh the list from user's behaviours like adding/deleting"* - That's what your attempt is missing then.  Currently your code has no user interactions.  If you want to call `refresh()` in response to user actions then you need to do that.  You simply haven't finished building what you want to build, that's why it's not working the way you want.

Comment: But to "refresh at the beginning", the answer below demonstrates that.  Use the `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a useEffect hook to fetch data on the first render only. If not, the component fetches at every render, which happens every time the state is updated, which render the component ...

```
export const App = () => {
    const [nodes, setNodes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
      //Self calling async function
      //Be carefull to add a ; at the end of the last line
      (async () => {
        let data = await fetch(url)
        let json = await data.json()
        setNodes(data)
      })()
    },[])

    return (
      <div>
      {  nodes.map(node => <div>Value: {node}</div>)  }
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect

```
 export default function App() {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState([]);
  const refresh = async () => {
  let arr = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     arr.push(Math.random());
   }
   setNodes(arr);
 };
useEffect(() => {refresh(); }, []);

return (
<div className="App">
  {nodes.map((v) => (
    <div>value: {v}</div>
  ))}
 </div>
);}
```